# How to continuously update HTML tag to get values from EJS and backend?

Tags: html, node.js, ejs

I have a very basic requirement on my frontend where I want to update the incoming images every second but I'm not sure of how to do it...

Following is my tag where I want to update the values -

```
    <img id="receivedImage" src="<%= imageData %>" alt="Received Frame">
```

It receives data from the backend -

```
app.get('/receiver', function(req, res) {
    res.render('receiver', { imageData: receivedFrameData });
});


wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    console.log('Client connected.');

ws.on('message', function incoming(imageData) {
    console.log('Received frame from client.');
    console.log(imageData);
    receivedFrameData = imageData;
    
    socketio.emit('frame', imageData); // Emit the frame data using Socket.IO
});

ws.on('close', function close() {
    console.log('Client disconnected.');
});
```

});

Currently I'm refreshing the entire page to re-render the new `src` but that seems to be a very shabby approach. Can someone guide me here ?

Comment: Consider using `ws` to make the updates.